# Error al validar campo unique dinamico Request Laravel

Tags: laravel, validación

Mi problema es que al momento de quere hacer un Update en un formulario me sale el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `trabajadores` where
>   `correo` = correo2@correo.com and `id` <> 2)

Pero en mi tabla no existe el campo 'id'...entonces donde esta el error?

Mi Modelo Trabajador:

```
public $table = 'Trabajadores';

    protected $primaryKey = 'IdTrabajador';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'correo', 'contra',
    ];

public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Rol', 'asignar_role', 'trabajador_id', 'role_id');
    }
```

Mi Request donde hago la validacion: TrabajadorEditarRequest

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nombre'=> 'required',
            'correo'=> 'required|unique:trabajadores,correo,'.$this->route('usuario')
        ];
    }
```

Mi Controlador donde llamo la funcion Update:

```
public function update(TrabajadorEditarRequest $request, $id)
    {   
        $trabajador=Trabajador::findOrFail($id);
        $trabajador->update($request->all());
         return back()->with('info', 'Usuario Actualizado');
    }
```

Y...porque me sale esto ---> correo2@correo.com and `id` <> 2 ??

Comment: ¿Con qué campo intentas comparar la variable `$id` que tienes como parámetro en el método update?

Comment: @Shaz mmm...creo que te entendi...entonces...como pondria el $id dentro del metodo update? Me podrias ayudar que no se muy bien sobre esto..pense que el request mandaba todos los datos del formulario..

Comment: La verdad es que nunca se entendió lo que querías resolver en este pregunta.

Comment: @Shaz la verdad es que yo no sabia exactamente de donde salia la columna 'id' que salia error, pero segun la respuesta que esta abajo. Solo me faltaba agregar el nombre la columna del modelo donde queria que ignore mi correo en rules. Al agregar eso, ya no me salio error y todo trabaja bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda tu codigo esta bien, tu único problema ha sido quen en la validacion del Request se te olvido poner el último parametro que es el nombre del ID del Modelo Trabajador.

-Aquí la solucion:

```
public function rules()
{
return [
     'nombre'=> 'required',
     'correo'=> 'required|unique:trabajadores,correo,'.$this->usuario.', IdTrabajador'
        ];
}
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Gracias amigo!! Al fin me salio, no pude creer que solo era eso! Gracias!!

Comment: @LaloLanda Si, por solo un parametro te salen errores, suele pasar. Suerte (y)

Comment: Muchas gracias! :D